# containskey always returns false even when key is in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

i want to check if a dictionary contains a key but it always returns false when i know the key is in the dictionary i done a bit of research and overriding the equals and hashchecks seems to do what i need but i cant get it to work can someone help me please here is the code to check the key and dictionary objects

```
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, blueinfo> blueprizes = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, blueinfo>();
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, yellowinfo> yellowprizes = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, yellowinfo>();

    public static List<string[]> ExecuteStringCommand(SQLiteCommand command, int columncount)
    {
            List<string[]> values = new List<string[]>();
            SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                List<string> row = new List<string>();
                row.Add("f2e135cdfb28407081bcca9a99a3148b");
                if (Program.blueprizes.ContainsKey(row[0]))//line always returns false
                    row.Add(Program.blueprizes[row[0]].Name1);
                if (Program.yellowprizes.ContainsKey(row[0]))//line always returns false
                    row.Add(Program.yellowprizes[row[0]].Name2);
                else
                    row.Add("Prize not found");
                values.Add(row.ToArray());
            }
            reader.Close();
            return values;
    }

class blueinfo
{
    static List<string> row = new List<string>();
    public blueinfo(string[] dbdata)
    {
        Name1 = dbdata[0];
        Id1 = dbdata[1];
        row.Add(dbdata[1]);
    }
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Id1 { get; set; }
    public static string[] dbdata1
    {
        get { return row.ToArray(); }
    }

}

class yellowinfo
{
    public yellowinfo(string[] dbdata)
    {
        Name2 = dbdata[0];
        Id2 = dbdata[1];
    }

    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    public string Id2 { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code that adds the items:

```
List<string[]> values = new List<string[]>();
line="prize 1=f2e135cdfb28407081bcca9a99a3148b"
values.Add(line.Split('='));

foreach (string[] row in values)
{
    if (blue == true)
        Program.blueprizes.TryAdd(row[1], new blueinfo(row));
    else
        Program.yellowprizes.TryAdd(row[1], new yellowinfo(row));
}
```

Comment: Can you please show just piece of code and data that reproduces the problem (i.e. add one element to dictionary and show what key could not be found). Note that likely answer is to use `String.Trim` before search and pass [StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when creating dictionary with [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287107%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor.

Comment: both keys are exactly the same and i cant ignore the case heres an example string f2e135cdfb28407081bcca9a99a3148b

Comment: Please make sample smaller but still demonstrating the problem and show data inline in the sample (instead of querying SQL), otherwise there is no way to answer your question. For what we can say there is exactly one key in the dictionary and it does not match any of the values you try to look up.

Comment: there edited o provide inline data samples

Comment: Why are you using `ConcurrentDictionary`?

Comment: i was using dictionary and found online concurrent dictionary might fix the problem but it didnt

Comment: What did you find online that you thought might have been the issue?

Comment: i found soloutions saying overriding the equals and hashcheck function should fix it but i cant get them to work

Comment: But that is nothing to do with `ConcurrentDictionary`. Also, overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` is useful when the key is one of your objects, but that's not the case here as your key is a string. (As a side note, you shouldn't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on an object where the fields are mutable. Doing so will break dictionaries.)

Comment: is there any soloution to this then i have no idea what to do when both strings re the exact same

Comment: Debug. Before the ContainsKey statement, put a line like `List<string> keysList = Program.blueprizes.Keys.ToList()` (you might need to import the System.Linq namespace). Set a breakpoint right after the line, and when the breakpoint hits, look what is in keysList, and compare it to what you have in row[0].

Comment: all the strings are in the keylist fine so i tried this but it didnt work either                     List<string> keysList = Program.blueprizes.Keys.ToList();
                    if (keysList.Contains(row[0]))

Comment: Well either (A) the row[0] value is not in the keylist, or (B) the code in your question is not the real code, or (C) your ConcurrentDictionary is not *System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary* as everybody here assumes. Choose one of these three options...

Comment: the code in question was copied straight from the program the concurrent dictionary is from system.collections and row[0] is definately in the list i can screen it if you want

Comment: heres a couple screen shots to show the list and the key its searching for http://i.imgur.com/ZScKrZs.png http://i.imgur.com/SsJelpt.png

Comment: `row[0]` on your screenshot clearly ends with a space character, but `keysList[5]` does not, so they are not equal.

Comment: Exactly, @max is spot on...

Comment: oh did not see that let me look into it

Comment: works fine my bad all this cause i was using a db that my other program made that added spaces where it shouldnt have thanks all question solved

Comment: The very first comment suggested using `Trim` on the keys. You should have tried that when it was suggested to you.

Answer (score 1):

- You do if / if / else, didn't you meant if / elseif / else ?
- I guess that this is why it outputs "Prize not found" for all blue prizes (it always branch on th final else for them)

Many errors/defects in the code:

- Prefer then "using" directive when manipulating streams and readers (SQLiteDataReader)
- class nmae should start with a Capital letter: BlueInfo, YellowInfo
- You call Program.blueprizes.TryAdd without checking the returned boolean ? Then how do you know that the call succeeded ? (It might not for many reasons on a concurrent dictionary)

Comment: Well spotted of the `elseif`. +1

Answer (score -1):

When you add items you are using `row[1]` and when you are checking for the key you are using `row[0]`. Maybe that is the issue? I don't know what `row[0]` and `row[1]` are, but they might not be exactly the same.

Comment: ther different variables in the form called from a foreach function so no thats not it sorry